# Rotate file name in script on the 1st of every month

Tags: ksh, aix

I have a script that runs every 5 minutes in the crontab and writes output to the same file. I want to move this file and append the date for the month on the 1st.

So far I have this logic in place:

```
date=`date +"%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M"`
date1=`date +"%d%m%Y%H%M"`
condition=`date +"01/%m/%Y-00:00"`

if [[ $date == $condition ]];then
  mv variable_check.txt variable_check-${date1}.txt
  mv ADT_`hostname`_active_users.txt ADT_`hostname`_active_users-${date1}.txt
else
  :
fi
```

I am not saying the above doesn't work, but is there perhaps a more preferred method of achieving what I need done.

Comment: What you specified sounds like the log rotation sub-system.

Comment: Assuming your logging script run in crontab at minutes */5, it might be wise to run the flip of the log at 23:58 to avoid timing conflicts (like the logger already has the file open before you rename it). Hard to run a cron job on last day of month -- typically, you run it on day 28-31, and have it check if tomorrow is day 01. Better would be to crontab the flip and logger consecutive in the same job at 00:00 on day 01, and make separate cron jobs for all the other days 2-31 in the month, and 5-59/5 minutes on the 1st.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use `logrotate`